# Iterate a characters or numbers in a loop in R

Tags: r

Quite new to R so this may be an easy answer. 
I have a list of characters. I want to remove the last letter and iterate it by one so A becomes B, 1 becomes 2 etc.

```
waferlist<-c('L2MLQ','L2MIW','L2MK0','L2ML6','L2MO2','L2MHE','L2MK4','L2MN6','L2MLM')

for (i in waferlist)
{

lastchar<-substr(i,5,6)           #Get last character

k<-lastchar==LETTERS             #Is it a Letter

pos<-min(which(k==TRUE))        #Find letter position and itterate
pos<-pos+1
pos<-LETTERS[pos]
```

The problem I'm having is if the last character is a number, it returns it as an `Inf` or `NA_character_` as its not in LETTERS.

I've tried to find a way to select these non results below but it doesn't see it as a `TRUE/FALSE` statement so it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

```
     if(pos==Inf | pos==NA_character_)
    {
       lastchar<-as.numeric(lastchar)
       pos<-lastchar+1
    }
```

Comment: What does 9 become?  What does Z become?  I would guess zero and A, respectively, cycling back to the beginning but you should clarify that.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get back to base 36 with `strtoi(waferlist, 36)+1`

Comment: Sorry Richard, the Ids are setup so they will never end in a 9 or a Z so I don't need to worry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an efficient solution (assuming you are using capitals),

```
res <- sapply(waferlist, function(i) {
    out <- utf8ToInt(i)
    out[[nchar(i)]] <- out[[nchar(i)]] + 1
    if (out[[nchar(i)]] == 91) out[[nchar(i)]] <- 65
    ## For 9 cycling back to 0?
    else if (out[[nchar(i)]] == 58) out[[nchar(i)]] <- 48
    intToUtf8(out)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `gsubfn` to replace the last character by the next number or alphabet by using an `if/else` condition.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('(.)$', function(x) if(grepl('[0-9]', x))
    as.numeric(x)+1 else LETTERS[match(x, LETTERS)+1], waferlist)
#[1] "L2MLR" "L2MIX" "L2MK1" "L2ML7" "L2MO3" "L2MHF" "L2MK5" "L2MN7" "L2MLN"
```

In the case of `Z` and 9 as last characters

```
LETTERS1 <- c(LETTERS[-1], LETTERS[1])
NUM <- c(1:9,0)
gsubfn('(.)$', function(x) if(grepl('[0-9]', x)) 
   NUM[match(x, NUM)+1] else LETTERS1[match(x, LETTERS1)+1], waferlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do base R:

```
alphabet = c(LETTERS, 'A')
dic      = as.character(c(0:9,0))

sapply(waferlist, function(w){
    el = gsub('.*(.{1})$','\\1',w)

    if(is.na(as.numeric(el))) dic = alphabet 

    gsub('.{1}$', dic[pmatch(x=el, table=dic)+1], w)
})

# "L2MLR" "L2MIX" "L2MK1" "L2ML7" "L2MO3" "L2MHF" "L2MK5" "L2MN7" "L2MLN"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr way:

```
library(stringi)

prefix = function(df, prefix) {
  names(df) = paste(prefix, 
                    names(df), 
                    sep = "_")
  df
}


letter_key = 
  data_frame(letter = 
               letters %>% 
               stri_trans_toupper) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n() )

next_letter = 
  letter_key %>%
  mutate(next_n = n + 1) %>%
  left_join(letter_key %>% prefix("next"))

data_frame(wafer = waferlist) %>%
  mutate(letter =  wafer %>% stri_sub(-1)) %>%
  left_join(next_letter) %>%
  mutate(next_character = ifelse(is.na(next_letter),
                                 letter %>% 
                                   as.numeric %>% 
                                   `+`(1),
                                 next_letter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to base 10 and add 1 then convert back.  Matlab has a dec2base function and this copy might work - and there must be a package that has better support for this kind of base conversion (or just addition in base36)

```
waferlist
[1] "L2MLQ" "L2MIW" "L2MK0" "L2ML6" "L2MO2" "L2MHE" "L2MK4" "L2MN9" "L2MLZ"

dec2base( strtoi(waferlist,36)+1, 36)
[1] "L2MLR" "L2MIX" "L2MK1" "L2ML7" "L2MO3" "L2MHF" "L2MK5" "L2MNA" "L2MM0"



dec2base <- Vectorize( function(x, base)
{  
   n<-ceiling(log(x+1, base)) 
   z <- c(0:9, LETTERS)   
   r <-  vector("character", n)
   for (j in n:1)
   {
      r[j] <- z[x %% base + 1]
      if (j > 1) x <- x %/% base
   }
   r <- paste(r, collapse="")
   r
})
```